# "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." when applying function to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, datetime

I have two dataframe `df1` and `subdf`.

`df1` looks something like this:

```
from pandas import Timestamp, Timedelta
df = pd.DataFrame({'station_key': {1300234: 'CV000011', 1300235: 'CV000011'},'charger_key': {1300234: 'CV00001101', 1300235: 'CV00001101'},'cid': {1300234: '01', 1300235: '01'},'x': {1300234: '33.489125', 1300235: '33.489125'},'y': {1300234: '126.487631', 1300235: '126.487631'},'snm': {1300234: '에코티엘(제주)', 1300235: '에코티엘(제주)'},'addr': {1300234: '제주특별자치도 제주시 연동 251-69외 ',1300235: '제주특별자치도 제주시 연동 251-69외 '},'addr_jibun': {1300234: '-', 1300235: '-'},'started_at': {1300234: Timestamp('2020-11-03 20:56:31'),1300235: Timestamp('2020-11-03 23:10:12')},'ended_at': {1300234: Timestamp('2020-11-03 23:10:12'),1300235: Timestamp('2020-11-03 23:40:12')},'status': {1300234: '2', 1300235: '1'},'day': {1300234: 'Tuesday', 1300235: 'Tuesday'},'time_usage': {1300234: Timedelta('0 days 02:13:41'),1300235: Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00')},'start': {1300234: Timestamp('2020-11-03 00:00:00'),1300235: Timestamp('2020-11-03 00:00:00')},'end': {1300234: Timestamp('2020-11-03 00:00:00'),1300235: Timestamp('2020-11-03 00:00:00')},'start_hour': {1300234: 20, 1300235: 23},'end_hour': {1300234: 23, 1300235: 23},'start_minute': {1300234: 56, 1300235: 10},'end_minute': {1300234: 10, 1300235: 40}})
```

And the subdf looks something like this:

```
subdf = pd.DataFrame({'start': {1300234: Timestamp('2020-11-03 00:00:00'),4849001: Timestamp('2020-11-03 00:00:00')},'station_key': {1300234: 'CV000011', 4849001: 'CV000271'},'charger_key': {1300234: 'CV00001101', 4849001: 'CV00027101'},'cid': {1300234: '01', 4849001: '01'},'x': {1300234: '33.489125', 4849001: '33.452903'},'y': {1300234: '126.487631', 4849001: '126.572552'},'snm': {1300234: '에코티엘(제주)', 4849001: '제주첨단과학단지(엘리트빌딩)'},'0_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'1_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'2_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'3_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'4_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'5_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'6_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'7_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'8_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'9_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'10_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'11_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'12_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'13_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'14_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'15_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'16_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'17_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'18_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'19_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'20_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'21_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'22_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0},'23_occupation': {1300234: 0, 4849001: 0}})
```

The `_occupation` columns represent the hour so there are 24 columns like that ranging from `0_occupation` to `23_occupation`

The function that I am trying to apply to `df1` is as follows:

```
def time_add(x):
    s_date = x['start']
    e_date = x['end']
    s_hour = x['start_hour']
    e_hour = x['end_hour']
    s_min = x['start_minute']
    e_min = x['end_minute']
    if(s_date == e_date):
        first_range = list(range(s_hour+1, e_hour))
        subdf.loc[(subdf["charger_key"] == x['charger_key']) & (subdf["start"] == s_date), str(s_hour)+"_occupation"]+=((60 - s_min)/60)*100
        for i in first_range:
            subdf.loc[(subdf["charger_key"] == x['charger_key']) & (subdf["start"] == s_date), str(i)+"_occupation"] = 1
        subdf.loc[(subdf["charger_key"] == x['charger_key']) & (subdf["start"] == s_date), str(e_hour)+"_occupation"]+=(e_min/60)*100
    else:
        first_range = list(range(s_hour+1, 24))
        subdf.loc[(subdf["charger_key"] == x['charger_key']) & (subdf["start"] == s_date), str(s_hour)+"_occupation"]+=((60 - s_min)/60)*100
        for i in first_range:
            subdf.loc[(subdf["charger_key"] == x['charger_key']) & (subdf["start"] == s_date), str(i)+"_occupation"] = 1
        second_range = list(range(0, e_hour))
        for i in second_range:
            subdf.loc[(subdf["charger_key"] == x['charger_key']) & (subdf["start"] == s_date+1), str(i)+"_occupation"] = 1
        subdf.loc[(subdf["charger_key"] == x['charger_key']) & (subdf["start"] == s_date+1), str(e_hour)+"_occupation"]+=(e_min/60)*100
```

However when I try to apply this by doing `time_add(df1)` an error is raised:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I looked this up and this error seems to occur when using `and` and `or` instead of `&` and `|` but this isn't the case in my function.

The full traceback of the error is as follows
[image]

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
if(s_date == e_date):
```

The `s_date` and `e_date` variables are not single values, but *entire columns* from your Pandas data frame. What does it mean when you are comparing them? Do you want to check if *all* values in one column are equal to the other? Or do you want to check if *at least one* value is equal to the corresponding one? Or do you want to do different things to the rows depending on whether the corresponding values in those two columns are equal?

```
if (s_date == e_date).all():
    # True if ALL values are equal.
```

Or,

```
if (s_date == e_date).any():
    # True if AT LEAST ONE value is equal.
```

Comment: Hi Dietrich thank you for your feedback. It seems that I was unclear on this matter. I am trying to apply a function for all rows on df1 and append values to subdf. If the values for df1[''start']==df1['end'], I want to append to subdf accordingly. ANd if it doesn't I want to append subdf according to the else statement

Comment: As I said, `df['start'] == df['end']` is ambiguous. What do you mean by that? Do you mean all rows? Any row? Do you want to do something different per row?

Answer (score 0):

As Dietrich pointed out, `s_date` and `e_date`, and all the other variables declared at the top of your function, are `Series`'s. They're whole columns from your dataframe. But I suspect that's not what you what. You're trying to run `time_add` for each row. But you're not doing that, because you're calling `time_add(df1)`. There it will be executed on the whole dataframe, and indexing it will return a whole column.

Change

```
time_add(df1)
```

to

```
df = df1.apply(time_add, axis=1)
```